# Editing shape in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, field-calculator, editing

I want to edit the shape of a line segment using the calculate field. This runs during an edit session, but don't run without.

How can I turn on edit inside a model and the turn it of after the calculate field operation?

The calculate field for the SHAPE@ turns and extends multiple line segments.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by adding a script to the model and running it as a python code insted of as a "Calculate field" tool.

Comment: Birks, if possible show your code that you use to solve the problem. This helps others persons who have the same problem.